# Javascript function changes behavior when passing element ID vs. hard coding it

Tags: javascript, html-table, getelementbyid

I have the following Javascript that on a single mouse click in a table cell with id="freq-table" populates consecutive `<input>` form fields with id="searchTerm(x)" with the cell's value. It's referenced in the `<body>` tag as:

```
<body onload="populateFields()>
```

and `<table>` tag as:

```
<table onclick="populateFields()> 

var index=0;
function populateFields(){
    var ft_id = document.getElementById("freq-table");    
    var alltds = ft_id.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i in alltds) {
        alltds[i].onclick = function () {
            if(index==0) {
                searchTerm1.value = this.innerHTML;
            } else {
                setThis(this.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
    if (index<2) {
        index++;
    } else {
        index = 1;
    }
}

function setThis(value) {
    document.getElementById("searchTerm"+index).value = value;
}
```

When trying to make the function more universal by passing the element id (as follows), it now takes a SECOND mouse click to start populating the fields.

```
<table onclick="populateFields(this)" id="freq-table">

function populateFields(element){
   var alltds = element.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

What is it about the revision that's changing the behavior? Am I just incorrectly passing the id? Or is  revised function now expecting a variable to be passed to it in `<body>` tag? It's confusing because: If I am incorrectly passing the id, why would the function work consecutively AFTER the first mouse click? What is the fix for this, please?

Comment: Why use `getElementById` to fetch an element that you already have? `document.getElementById(element.id)` Just use the `element`.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo when composing my post. Corrected above. Thanks.

Comment: well, in your revision you're losing the body onload, right?

Comment: Yes, @Christophe. That's what the problem seemed to me. Being very new at javascript, if I hard-coded the 'freq-table' id in the body tag to get the onload working, how could other tables with different ids take advantage of the onload? i.e., I could get it to work for 'freq-table' on the first click-but not others...

Comment: Yes, @Jack. The function was originally used for just one table and, with the body onload="populateFields()" and the 'freq-table' id hard-coded in the function as document.getElementById("freq-table"), it worked fine on first click. But I'd like to use this function for another table that has a different id (and accompanying css associated with the id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some heavy code here, where the first table click (or body onload) sets additional click event handlers.

What you should do instead is use [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation). With event delegation, the click event handler is attached to the table but knows which cell was clicked (the target).

[Update] Code sample based on the above article:

```
var index=0;
var tableIds=["freq-table1","freq-table2","freq-table3"];
for (var i=0;i<tableIds.length;i++) {
var currentId=tableIds[i];
var table=document.getElementById(currentId);
table.onclick = function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  while(target != this) {
    if (target.nodeName == 'TD') {
        // target is our cell
        setThis(target.innerHTML);
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  // increment index modulo 3
  index=(index+1)%3;
}; // end of onclick function
}  // end of for loop
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/srVmF/2/

Comment: I've been at this all day--reading, studying, trying different things--and I think you might be right at the end of the day. I'm going to look into this with fresh eyes in the AM. Thank you for your time and consideration. :)

Comment: Thank you, kindly, @Christophe. I had this working when I'd hard-coded 'freq-table' in the original function but I wanted to make this universal to apply to different tables on the same page that have different ids (which I can't change). I'm new at JavaScript: Will your rewrite above work if I change 'var table=document.getElementById("freq-table")' to 'var table=document.getElementsByClass(table-class-var);' and pass the different classes from different tables to it? Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Andreas3204 the point is that you didn't really have it working with your initial code, as the function populateFields had to run twice to get the job done. I have added a loop to make it work for multiple tables, but of course this is just one way to do it. If you'd like to discuss it further, I'd recommend to set up a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: [Sorry, I meant that I had it working when id was hard-coded...] I'm in awe of the consideration you and others have shown me here. I am definitely going to sandbox it from scratch today with a fiddle. Thank you again, @Christophe.

Comment: I have your solution in this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreas3204/srVmF/1/) It does solve the different ids issue. Thank you. As written though, it only populates the first input field regardless of which of the two tables is clicked. Also, js debugger in Chrome shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null" in this line `if (target.nodeName == "TD") {` for any click in table with id="freq-table1". Thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the code and the demo http://jsfiddle.net/srVmF/2/. This could still be improved, but at least you get the idea of how delegation works.

Comment: that's brilliant! And very flexible, too, with your use of modulo for adding other incremental `<input>` fields. I did read a lot about delegation this AM but have a long ways to go... Thank you again, kindly, for your time and consideration. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the call can come from the TD or the TR element. So, the first time the id will be 'undefined'.

Why not call the function with the event and verify the tag name:

```
<table onclick="populateFields(event)" id="freq-table">
```

Javascript

```
function populateFields(e) { 

 var source = e.target || e.srcElement;
 if (e.tagName == 'table') {
 var ft_id = document.getElementById(source.id);
```

Comment: Thank you, @pxx. I've been at this the entire day and will try your solution tomorrow--and will mark / comment accordingly. Thanks. :)

Comment: The `source` will hold whatever nested element was clicked instead of the actual `table` element, so you'll get the wrong ID.

Comment: Yes, so to avoid this it asks for the tag name

Answer (score 2):

Instead of being populated on page load, now you have to click on the table before it populates the fields.

You could leave the page load handler:

```
<body onload="populateAllFields()">
```

For every table you add a class:

```
<table class="mytable">
```

Then, the code:

```
function populateAllFields()
{
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('mytable'), populateFields);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. I copied these verbatim, removed the ...getElementsById from populateFields() and [I assume] you wanted me to place the onclick="populateAllFields" in the table tag, as well. I'm getting no results.

`<body onload="populateAllFields()">`

`<table onclick="populateAllFields()" class="mytable"`

Comment: @Andreas3204 No, you shouldn't have the `onlick` attribute for the tables. Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I really appreciate your time and consideration. I had tried it without and with the onclick. It's out now. I added `alert(1);` to populateAllFields() and `alert(2);` to populateFields() and verified they are both getting called on page load. This is the first table element: `<table id="freq-table" class="table-list mytable">` and this is the 2nd: `<table class="mytable">` and getElementsById was removed. I'm stumped here. (No JavaScript errors.)

Comment: @Andreas3204 `populateFields()` should be called twice actually.

Comment: Hmmm... Only once. Even just added a dummy table outside of all other divs: `<table class="mytable"><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>` and only got one call to populateFields().

Comment: @Andreas3204 You really shouldn't debug with `alert()`; use a proper JavaScript debugger, found in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28345/discussion-between-andreas3204-and-jack)

Answer (score 1):

Your `<body onload="populateFields()>` isn't passing the element you want, so the initial set that would be done when the page loads is no longer happening.

You can fix it by passing the ID instead, and give the `onload` handler the ID.

```
function populateFields(id){
    var ft_id = document.getElementById(id);    
    var alltds = ft_id.getElementsByTagName("td");
    // and so on...
}
```

---

```
<body onload="populateFields('freq-table')">


<table onclick="populateFields(this.id)">
```

Comment: Thanks, @am not i am. As stated, goal is to have it work universally (i.e. on other tables). So if I hard-code 'freq-table' id into the body tag, that could fix it for that id but I suspect that would preclude it from working on first click for tables with different ids. Pardon my ignorance here: I'm really new at Javascript.

Comment: @Andreas3204: It comes down to what you actually need for a given situation. If there are other tables that need to be set up like this when the page loads, then you need to run that function for each table. There are various was to accomplish this.